# How to automatically compute Greatest Common RATIONAL Divisor in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to set a function in R to compute the Greatest Common RATIONAL Divisor of a vector. So I'm not working with a vector of integers, but of numerics. And from this vector I would like to automatically determine the highest numeric that can divide all the values in the vector and result in a integer. Which is very difficult with floating-point arithmetic used in R.

To give an example, lets say that I would like to find the highest common rational divisor of 5, 0.37 and 0.02. It's 0.01, but how can I automate this, taking into account that with floating-point arithmetic 0.37 will for instance be considered like 0.3700000000000000000000000005271 in R (something like that) ? With that problem I can't easily compute the lowest order of decimal (10^-2 in my example), or if you prefer the lowest one that has significance for me as user.

The fact that the result in itself will have floating-point-like error (e.g. 0.0100000000000000000000008465 in place of 0.01) is not a problem. However ideally the solution should be the most general possible (capable of working with vectors having extremely different values (10^20 and 10^-20 for instance).

Comment: Your first step should be to establish a precision you want to work on. Then you can either round the doubles to that precision or use arbitrary precision numbers (package Rmpfr). And then you only need to apply your algorithm (which hopefully doesn't create its own precision issues).

Comment: I considered that way, but wouldn't there be a way to let the algorithm determine by itself that precision ? Or lets put it in another way: I have a very large range of numbers in the vector, but I still want to know the amount of significative numbers in each of them. Lets say 123,4 and 0.000001023524. Defining a precision is more difficult. My first instinct was to normalise everything by its power of 10, so 100 and 0.000001 in my example, to obtain 1.234 and 1.023524. For these normalised numbers I define a precision (lets say 16 digits). But arriving there is already difficult.

Comment: Can you explain how a largest common rational divisor could be useful? I'm having a hard time imagining a sane use case.

Comment: I'm a geologist working on time series. But geological time series are often unevenly sampled (that's an unavoidable field reality). Therefore I often have to use interpolation. But that interpolation has to be very conservative. Therefore I want to interpolate using the largest common rational divisor. Now I get your question: why ask for a solution with that large extremes in mind ? Well for me the function has to be general and intuitive, so that every user can use it without worry. And if the user digs further, I want him to have an intuitive way of dealing with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: But wouldn't it be better to reduce this to an integer problem? For geological questions you probably don't care about sub-minute time-precision. So, why don't you simply work with minutes (or seconds if you require more precision)?

Comment: Well we work in the depth domain (making it a depth-series ? anyway,...), so we speak in meters, cm or millimeters. But anyway that is not the point: I want to automate the whole process. I can convert into integers by hand, no problem. But this the point of using informatics: automating it. If I have to resort to it yes I will ask the user to transform it so it works, but I would like to work around this: automatisation is the key here.

Comment: I don't get it. If you can convert by hand, you can convert automatically. Anyway, as stated ("compute Greatest Common RATIONAL Divisor in R"), you have a very difficult problem,not the least because you can't know which rational number is *meant*  to be the input. E.g., how do you know that `0.3700000000000000000000000005271` is meant to be `0.37` and not `0.3700000000000000000000000005`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197918/discussion-between-sebastien-wouters-and-roland).

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. So the basic idea is to divide everything by the smallest value, to multiply by integers, until every value  is made of integers. This is controlled via the floor() function, which allows to have explicit control over the level of tolerance. I added some control to the amount of possibilities it tests, to make it kind of efficient, but I'm not sure this is the best method. Anyway I'll put this in the `StratigrapheR` package

```
divisor <- function(x, tolerance = 8, relative = T, tries = 4, speak = T)
{

  if(!(isFALSE(relative) | isTRUE(relative))) {
    stop("The 'relative' parameter should be TRUE or FALSE'")
  }

  if(!(isFALSE(speak) | isTRUE(speak))) {
    stop("The 'speak' parameter should be TRUE or FALSE'")
  }

  x <- unique(x)
  x <- x[x != 0]

  # Divide by smallest

  mx <- min(x)
  d  <- x/mx

  if(!relative){

    # Test if tolerance is of lower order than the smallest

    if(-log10(mx) > tolerance) {
      stop(paste("If 'relative' is FALSE, the smallest value (zero excepted)",
                 "should of higher order than the order",
                 "defined by the 'tolerance' parameter"))
    }

  }

  # Test the dispersion of values

  general_tolerance <- 15 # Order of digits affected by floating-point

  if(log10(max(x)) >= (general_tolerance - tolerance)){
    stop(paste("The range of 'x' values is too large to find a meaningful",
               "greatest common rational divisor.",
               "To solve this problem you can change the values in x or",
               " lower the 'tolerance' parameter (i.e. the",
               "tolerance for floating-point aritmetics):in the later case be",
               "critical of the result."))
  }

  # Test and remove values that are multiples of the smallest value

  remain1 <- (d - floor(d + 10^-(tolerance - 1)))
  if(!relative) remain1 <- remain1 * mx

  rzero1 <-  abs(remain1) < 10^-tolerance

  d <- d[!rzero1]

  if(length(d) == 0) {

    if(!relative){

      res <- round(mx, tolerance)

    } else {

      res <- signif(mx, tolerance)

    }

  } else {

    # Multiply d [x/min(x)] by integers, and test if
    # this returns only integers within tolerance

    ld <- length(d)

    try_order_OLD <- 0
    try_order_i   <- 6 - ceiling(log10(ld))

    for(i in seq_len(as.integer(tries))){

      if(speak) {
        print(paste("Try ",i,": 10^",try_order_i,
                    " possibilities tested", sep = ""))
      }

      t <- 1:(10^try_order_i)
      t <- t[-(1:(10^try_order_OLD))]

      lt <- length(t)

      tmat <- matrix(rep(t,ld), ncol = ld)
      dmat <- matrix(rep(d, lt), ncol = ld, byrow = T)

      test <- dmat * tmat

      remain2 <- (test - floor(test + 10^-(tolerance - 1)))
      remain2 <- remain2/tmat
      if(!relative) remain2 <- remain2 * mx

      rzero2 <-  abs(remain2) < 10^-tolerance

      rzero2 <- matrix(as.integer(rzero2), ncol = ld)

      test[which(rowSums(rzero2) == ld),]

      res <- mx/t[which(rowSums(rzero2) == ld)[1]]

      if(!is.na(res)) break

      try_order_OLD <- try_order_i
      try_order_i   <- try_order_i + 1

    }

  }

  return(res)

}
```